# Intel FPGA OpenCL work-group scheduling

Tags: fpga, intel

I have a question about work-group scheduling on multiple CUs in Intel FPGA. As work-groups are assigned to available CUs, when is a CU considered available? Is it when the last work-item of the previous work-group has abandoned​ the pipeline or when it is at its second stage (so every stage of the pipeline is occupied by the previous work-group except the first one)? This decision is taken by the hardware scheduler, but I haven't found any public documentation explaining any of this.

Edit: I'm talking about the automatic process that takes place when using Intel OpenCL SDK for FPGA, not a custom design with HDL.

Comment: Um, I'm no expert on this subject, but Intel is a manufacturer (probably the second largest) of FPGAs, and what you do with these, including what kind of pipelined processing you put on there, is not their business?

Comment: Of course. Maybe this needs clarification. I'm talking about the mapping produced by Intel OpenCL SDK for FPGA, not a custom one.

Comment: @HastatusXXI It sounds like what you're asking about is more specific to the OpenCL architecture, then, than to Intel FPGAs (damn, it still feels weird saying Intel there instead of Altera...)

Comment: @HastatusXXI You should mention this in the question.

Comment: @Hearth What I'm asking is about the scheduling of work-groups and, given this is a decision about the physical mapping taken by Intel (since this is done automatically by their SDK) I guess it has to do more with Intel than with OpenCL.

Comment: @HastatusXXI it's specific to the OpenCL implementation done by some specific Intel tool. it's got little to do with the fact that it runs on intel FPGAs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller my point is the Intel tool always creates a pipeline architecture for every compute unit, and this is what arises my question. AFAIK this is not explicitly said in the OpenCL specification and Intel does not provide details about the scheduling in their implementation. This is why I'm asking.

Comment: yeah, but think about that: that makes this more of a programming question than an electrical engineering one, right? The much larger community of Stackoverflow.com might be the right place to ask.

Comment: @MarcusMüller maybe, but as the question is in regards to a hardware scheduler (whose details don't appear in any public Intel document I have come up to so far) I thought it might be more suited for this community. I'll ask there if you think it's more appropriate.

Comment: Edit your question to add detail, don't leave it in comments.